# Setting wal_keep_segments for PostgreSQL hot_standby

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am having a trouble setting up a PostgreSQL hot_standby. When attempting to start the database after running pg_basebackup, I receive, `FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000006440000008D has already been removed`, in the postgresql.log. After a brief discussion in IRC, I came to understand the error likely originates from a too low `wal_keep_segments` setting for my write intensive database..

How might I calculate, if possible, the proper setting for `wal_keep_segments`? What is an acceptable value for this setting?

What I am working with:

- Postgresql 9.3
- Debian 7.6

Answer (score 3):

`wal_keep_segments` could be estimated as the average number of new WAL segments per minute in the `pg_xlog` directory multiplied by the number of minutes across which you want to be safe for. Bear in mind that the rate is expected to increase after `wal_level` is changed from its default value of `minimal` to either `archive` or `hot_standby`. The only cost is disk space, which as you know by default is 16 MB per segment.

I typically use powers of 2 as values. At the rate of about 1 segment per minute, a value of 256 gives me about 4 hours in which to set up the standby.

You could alternatively consider using WAL streaming with `pg_basebackup`. This is per its `--xlog-method=stream` option. Unfortunately, at least as of 2013, per a [discussion on a PostgreSQL mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABUevEyKRO-fTKD_D_7JLRVdRbGtfsZczXhCjS3E5Him+wxOTQ@mail.gmail.com), setting `wal_keep_segments` to a nonzero value may still be recommended - this is to prevent risking the stream from being unable to keep up. If you do use `pg_basebackup` though, also don't forget `--checkpoint=fast`.

Comment: You can also turn on WAL archiving on the master and store as much WAL backlog as you have disk space.  The WAL archive is detached from the active database WAL (it's just a copy) and can have a history duration that far exceeds wal_keep_segments (on slower, cheaper disk too), allowing for many days of recovery room for the standby.

Comment: @RobertCasey Yes, I recall doing something like that. I also used `xz` for compression. It was too long ago.